# How to make node join the cluster (Pacemaker, Corosync 2 node setup) automatically after disconnection / unplugging?

Tags: redhat, cluster, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I have a 2 node cluster running Corosync and Pacemaker. If I physically unplug the network cable on one node, the other one becomes standalone.

But when I plug the network cable back in, I want it to automatically join the cluster, without any other human interference.

Is that doable?

Comment: Im not sure sure what u are pulling out the nic, are u testing failover? In that case, this isnt a great idea cuz its not really a node failure. It confuses both nodes as to the other might be down. Think of a master slave resource... When u pull the cable, the master thinks that slave is down, and the slave thinks the master is down and gets promoted to master. Classic race condition. If u want to test failover, use "pcs cluster standby node2" command. To bring it back use "unstandby"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, but you'll need to use some sort of reliable fencing/stonith; this will trigger a reboot of one node when you pull the network, allowing it to rejoin on startup: http://clusterlabs.org/doc/crm_fencing.html

Fencing is a very important, and often overlooked, concept in clustering.

You should also look into configuring redundant ring support in Corosync to avoid cluster partitions when there is a problem with a single communication link.